# MacOS swift why is getting image with path using NSUrl giving error "The file does not exist."

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I'm trying to get an image from a url path:

```
    @IBOutlet var pathControl: NSPathControl!
    let imgUrl = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: pathControl.stringValue)
```

which when i print it, it gives gives me:

```
    file:/Users/tristan/Images/simpson_bg.jpg -- file:///Users/tristanc/Library/Containers/com.parab3llum.Gif-wallpaper/Data/
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The file doesn’t exist.
```

This file is confirmed existing since I use path control. Yet I still get the error:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The file doesn’t exist.
```

Comment: Your app is sandboxed. You don't have access to your standard home folder.

Comment: I tried it. But instead it leads me to another set of folders and the same error: file:/Users/tristanbrankovic/Images/simpson_bg.jpg -- file:///Users/tristanbrankovic/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gif_wallpaper-ctteapukyerziwbqnqaoqyocfbli/Build/Products/Debug/

Comment: If you are trying to access folders in the standard home folder the framework redirects you to the application container in your case `/Users/tristanc/Library/Containers/com.parab3llum.Gif-wallpaper/Data/`. You have to use to API `url(for: in: appropriateFor: create: )` of FileManager to get the folders in the sandbox. Once again, *You don't have access to your standard home folder*.